# React.js onClick function to to render a table

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I  have an array of objects coming from two different APIs. The first API I am converting it to a bullet point using `<li>` tag. And the second API should be converted to a table using `<table\>` tag. What I want to do is whenever I click on the bullet point it should show the table with the appropriate data. I was successfully able to get the data from both APIs.

**The main problem I am having is, the `onClick()` function.**
First, after mapping the bullet point, the `onclick` function treat it as one gigantic click button. they are not seperated.
Second, when I tried to hard code it , since they are only 8 bullet points. I was not able to get the data on a table.

I start coding just about a month and half ago, I have been trying everything I know for the last five days. At this point I ran out of ideas. Please Help me guys thank you!

Here is what I have tried till now.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const reqMenu = "fake link";
  
  const reqDescription = "fake link";
  
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  
  const [description, setDescription] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getReq()
    getDesc()

  },[]);

  const getReq = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(reqMenu);
    const data = await response.json()
    setRecipes(data)
    // console.log(data)
  };

  const getDesc = async () => {
    const response= await fetch(reqDescription);
    const data = await response.json()
    setDescription(data)
    // console.log(data)
  }
  
  const ss = description.filter((e) =>  (e.short_name.startsWith("SS")))

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Menu Categories</h1>

        <div>
          <ul>
          {recipes.map((recipe ,id, index) => (
              <li key={id} onClick={() => 
                {if(index[0] = recipes[0]["short_name"]){
                    return <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                    {ss.map((s) =>{
                      <tr key={id}>
                      <td>{s.name}</td>
                      <td>{s.description}</td>
                    </tr>
                    })}
                  </table>
                  }}}>
               {recipe.name}-({recipe.short_name})
              </li>
          ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**What I am expecting is this**
[image: what the code should do]
Whenever I click on the bullet point, it should shows the table with appropiate data. Also title above the table should change the short name inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning JSX  from the onClick handler, what you want to do is render some JSX based on current selected item.

To do so you can save a reference to the data (not the template)

Example: `onClick={() => setVisibleTable(id)}`

Then somewhere else in the template you can decide to render a table based on the id.

```
{tables[id] && 
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    {tables[id].map((s) =>{
      <tr key={s.name}>
        <td>{s.name}</td>
        <td>{s.description}</td>
      </tr>
    })}
  </table>
}
```

Comment: that's great idea thank you. but how do I solve the problem of the bullet point. they all function as one bullet point. if I clicked on any of them, they gave me the same result

Comment: They give the same result, because the function in `onClick` is always the same.

If you read the function body, you will notice that it's always the same for each list item, hence it will always produce the same output.
You probably want to include some of the parameter of your loop (`recipe`, `id`) in your `onClick` to make the function somewhat "dynamic"